# How do I plot a complex equation in the form of a graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this complex equation that I need to plot on a graph. I first need to get some calculations because I do not know the value of the constants in that equation. So, I am using a trial and error method here.

The equation is like this

(4.0*pie*G*P*(C)^2(1-(C/radius)*arctan(C/radius)))^1/2

In this equation, G, pie, C, P are all constants but, I do not know the value of P and C.
I have a list of values for the radius that I need to plug into the equation along with all the constants to get a list of results which when plotted on the graph(with the radius being the parameter for the x-axis) would match an already drawn plot.

However, Im finding it hard to get the resultant values from the equation.

This is the code i have written

```
radius= pd.read_csv("radius.txt", header=None)
data.head()
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
pie=3.1415926535898
P = 4.07
C = 23
G = 6.687*10**11
rCDM = (4.0*pie*G*P*(C)**2(1-(C/radius)*atan(C/radius)))**1/2
print(rCDM)
```

The compiler keeps reporting an error and this is the error written.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/sessions/0fe9d9f21ef5287c/main.py", line 45, in <module>
    rCDM = (4.0*pie*G*P*(C)**2[1-(C/radius)*atan(C/radius)])**1/2
```

so I do not know how to get the values

Thanks for your time!

Comment: add the error report please.

Comment: I have added the edits

Comment: What is r? Is r = 0?

Comment: Also how does `[]` work with that equation? Shouldn't it be `()`

Comment: I'm extremely sorry for the mistake. My edits hadn't been saved. The radius in the equation is a list of values in a text file that I need to plug in the equation

Comment: Try inserting a `*` after `rCDM = (4.0*pie*G*P*(C)**2`

Comment: Also, you probably want to change `**1/2` to `**(1/2)`.